# Blender debug is crashing with error

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, build, blender

Now I try to build complete version of Blender. At step building and installing DLL I had not problems, but now when I try to debug Blender I receive:

```
'blender.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: D:\BLENDERBUILD4\bin\Debug\blender.exe
File: D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstring
Line: 1168

Expression: invalid null pointer
For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
(Press Retry to debug the application)
blender.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

Debugging stop on:

```
_STD_BEGIN
#ifdef _DEBUG
_CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Debug_message(const wchar_t     *message, const wchar_t *file, unsigned int line)
{   // report error and die
    if(::_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ASSERT, file, line, NULL, L"%s", message)==1)
    {
        ::_CrtDbgBreak();
    }
}
_CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Debug_message(const unsigned short *message, const unsigned short *file, unsigned int line)
{   // report error and die
    _Debug_message((wchar_t *) message, (wchar_t *) file, line);
}
#endif
```

What is a problem? May be I lost some DLL's or something else? If I start blender.exe it's crashing too. Sorry for noob-question, in coding I'm new.

Comment: Your code snippet shows where `::_CrtDbgBreak()` is called, which is similar to hitting breakpoint. But to find out WHY it is called you will have to go higher up the call stack. In other terms: The code you show does not cause the error, it just reports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it.
Just add in your Debug folder with blender.exe a 2.XX (in my case 2.78) folder from Install path with multiple Python scripts. That's it!